# FEBS Letters journal latex template

Tags: templates, journal

From where can I download latex template for FEBS letters Journal(Wiley)?
I am searching for it. I couldn't find the template. Your suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: This page suggests there is no specific template, just to use the `article` class: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1742-4658/homepage/ForAuthors.html#latexsub

Comment: This type of questions is very borderline on-topic here, IMHO. However, your comment, @darthbith, seems to be the correct answer, I think you can turn it into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page suggests there is no specific template, just to use the `article` class, although it appears to be for the FEBS Journal instead of FEBS Letters: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1742-4658/homepage/ForAuthors.html#latexsub